# Como puedo mostrar los likes de mi base de datos en un template de vue

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql, vue.js

estoy creando un foro que permite dar like a las preguntas que se hacen. Todas las preguntas las guardo en un array de objetos, algo asi:

```
questions: [
        {
          id: 1,
          question: "Esta es una pregunta",
          date: 1,
          hastags: "#juegos #comida",
          user: "josue_ayala27",
          likes: 56
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          question: "Pregunta #2",
          date: 13,
          hastags: "#jugar #correr",
          user: "jalex",
          likes: 12
        }
      ]
```

Al dar click en el icono de me gusta, ejecuto el siguiente metodo que me permite pintar el icono dando la ilusion que ya diste like:

```
addLike: function(likeActual, idActual) {
      var elemento = document.getElementById(idActual);
      if (elemento.getAttribute("type") == "regular") {
        var like = likeActual + 1;
        var id = idActual;
        this.questions.map(function(dato) {
          if (dato.id == id) {
            dato.likes = like;
          }
          elemento.setAttribute("type", "solid");
          return dato;
        });
      } else {
        var like = likeActual - 1;
        var id = idActual;
        this.questions.map(function(dato) {
          if (dato.id == id) {
            dato.likes = like;
          }
          elemento.setAttribute("type", "regular");
          return dato;
        });
      }
    }
```

Cada vez que doy click en like guardo un registro en la base de datos, mi tabla para guardar likes es algo asi:

```
Table{
  id_like int,
  id_publicacion int 
  id_usuario int
}
```

Lo que necesito es que al momento de recargar la pagina me sigan apareciendo seleccionado los likes que di.

Todas las peticiones a la base de datos las manejo con un JSON, ocupo php como backend.

La consulta que retorna mi array es simple, solo hago un:

```
Select * from publicaciones
```

Para que me retorne toda la informacion de las publicaciones.

Comment: Considera añadir como haces la consulta a tu base de datos

Comment: Claro, ya lo actualize, pero hago una simple consulta para llenar mi array en donde tengo mis publicaciones.

Comment: Haz un `LEFT JOIN` a la tabla de _likes_ por ID de publicación e ID de usuario, si los valores son `no nulos` quiere decir que el usuario ya dio like.

Comment: Tendria que crear un foreach y recorrer publicacion por publicacion?